# Shellscript with ambiguous redirect error

Tags: mysql, shell

My shellscript is not working:

```
#!/bin/bash
LIST="$(ls -rt *.log.*)"

for i in "$LIST"; do

echo $i

mysql --user=<user> --password=<passwd> <database> < $i

done
```

result: `./analisys.sh: line 5: $i: ambiguous redirect`

Can you help me?

Comment: I hope you're not *really* using all those angle brackets in there...

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't expand `$LIST` if you want to operate on each whitespace separated item. I.e remove the two `"`. You don't need them in the first occurrance either.

This should have been apparent when you listed the items with `echo $i`, I suspect all files where listed at once, and not each at a time.

```
#!/bin/bash
LIST=$(ls -rt *.log.*) # THIS LINE CHANGED

for i in $LIST; do # THIS LINE CHANGED

    echo $i
    mysql --user=<user> --password=<passwd> <database> < $i

done
```

Comment: Don't use `ls`: `for i in *.log.*`

Answer (score 0):

another way

```
cat *.log.* > dump.dump

mysql --user=<user> --password=<passwd> <database> < dump.dump
```

I thought something like

```
mysql --user=<user> --password=<passwd> <database> < `cat *.log.*`
```

would work to make it a 1 liner, but I still get ambiguous redirect.